# Get operations in domain driven design

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have an an entity A which has a relation to entity B and C.

Entity B and C can only be created when I create entity A in a transaction.

Thus I only have an A-Repository.cs

When I do a read/get operation on entity B in the context of A or with C outside the context of A.

Where do I put those get operations?

Comment: From your question I think A is an aggregate root and B and C are entities referenced by A. That's why you have an A repository, because an aggregate root associates one repository. Now you want to get access to B and C, you will have to get access to A first in your design. Alternatively, you can treat A,B,C as three aggregate roots and reference B, C in A by Id only, therefore you can use the lazy loading. and you can create UnitOfWork for repository<A>, repository<B> and repository<C>

Comment: useful reference: UnitOfWork - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576681/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusRepository http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-applicationDDD aggregate design - http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

Comment: A is the aggregate root yes. I do not want to have a Repo B and C extra for one single get method. So what is the right way doing this? I already use a UoW but this has nothing to do with designing repositories.

Comment: What does your “get operations” mean? to retrieve B and C?

Comment: To retrieve B and C with the Id of A. Just getting related data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On A, assuming A is the root entity of your aggregate, assuming you're applying the tactical patterns.

Comment: It's an answer *duh*. A instanceOfA; instanceOfA.GetB(idOfB); instanceOfA.GetC(idOfC); or better yet instanceOfA.DoSomethingWithB(idOfB, ...); instanceOfA.DoSomethingWithC(idOfC, ...);

Comment: I have never heard about the tactical pattern. You have any link please?

Comment: instanceOfA is an entity. You make db calls within your entities?

Comment: You load up the entire aggregate; the GetB/C or DoSomethingB/C methods happen in memory.

Comment: You apply Domain Driven Design and you never heard of the tactical patterns? Ouch. Here's some good advice on how to design aggregates http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

Comment: To be complete, if you were to use an ORM some of the entities might be loaded using Lazy Loading. So you might still be hitting the db upon accessing an entity. It doesn't, however, mesh that well with the philosophy of an aggregate as a consistency boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Your get operations for B and C belong in A. So, in A, you are looking at code like `public B b{get;}` and `public C c{get;}`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of aggregate, you need to retrieve aggregate from repository (A in your case) and then traverse the object graph to get local entities(B and C in your case).

```
A a = aRepository.findBy(id);
B b = a.getB();
C c = a.getC();
```

Some infrastructure issues have to be addressed. You may need an orm framework supporting lazy-loading if your domain models are also your persistent models and your store B and C in seperate tables from that of A.

Comment: I don't think that lazy loading is a good idea, when doing DDD.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio this is an feasible solution when the domain models and persistent models are the same group of objects. I think your point is "using the same objects for domain and persistence" is not a good idea :)

Comment: @Hippoom So to speak in another sample: You would put the getOrdersByCustomerId() in the customerRepository? following your analogy... right?

Comment: @Elisa No. I would put getOrdersByCustomerId() in orderRepository if order is an aggregate or customerRepository.findCustomerBy(id).getOrders() if customer is an aggregate and orders are it's local entities(But in real business, order is probably an aggregate).